# Pandas index isin method

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I'm having throuble working with the isin method when working with pandas indexes, it always returns False.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame(data=[['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]], index=['N01', 'N02', 'N03'])
df.index.isin(['01', '02'])
```

returns

```
array([False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `str.contains` and pass a regex pattern:

```
In[5]: df.index.str.contains('01|02')

Out[5]: array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

`isin` looks for exact matches which is why you get all `False` array returned

Answer (score 3):

`df.index.isin(['01', '02'])` method  in your example is checking if **each** of the values in the index is **equal** to **one of the values** in the range (similar to SQL).

Therefore in your case the check is:
`'N01'=='01' or 'N01' == '02'`
which is `False`

The correct usage of `.isin()` in your case would be:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame(data=[['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]], index=['N01', 'N02', 'N03'])
df.index.isin(['N01', 'N02'])
```

which will result in 
`array([True, True, False], dtype=bool)`