# How to test a set of values (not all) exist in a Pandas multiindex?

Tags: python, pandas

The `isin()` method applied to a Pandas index returns whether **each** index value is found in the passed set of values, but is there a possibility to test only a set of indexe values ?

In the multiIndex below I would like to test if an index with level name `s1` and level value `E` and level name `d1` and level value `future` exists. Problem is that I test index values that may not exist so selection method like `xs` or `loc` don' work.

```
df_routes.index
MultiIndex([('E', 'future',       'B', 'future'),
            ('E', 'future',       'B5', 'future'),
            ('E', 'future',       'B',   'spot'),
            ('B', 'future',       'B', 'future'),
            ('B', 'future',       'B5', 'future'),
            ('B', 'future',       'B',   'spot')],
           names=['s1', 'd1', 's2', 'd2'])
```

My problem is that `isin()` returns False when using `any` as index values :

```
df_routes.index.isin([('E', 'future', any, any)])

array([False, False, False, False, False, False])
```

The desired result would be :

```
array([True, True, True, False, False, False])
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44366968/pandas-index-isin-method/44367779) but the answer only works for index not multiindex.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna filter the dataframe using multi-index, just use `.loc`

```
df.loc[('E', 'future')]
```

Sample DataFrame

```
                     0
s1 d1     s2 d2
E  future B  future  1
          B5 future  2
          B  spot    3
B  future B  future  4
          B5 future  5
          B  spot    6
```

Ouput

```
           0
s2 d2
B  future  1
B5 future  2
B  spot    3
```

To create a boolean array

```
(df.index.get_level_values(0) == 'E') & (df.index.get_level_values(1) == 'future')
```

Comment: That's right but I would like to test if the index values exists (or is present in the index)

Comment: My problem is that sometimes index values I test don't exist in the multiindex

Comment: @Florent Updated answer